# Java check empty ArrayList as an class structure

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to create class structure as in this example:

```
public class SubjectListStructure {
    public String topic_id;
    public String topic_title;
    public String created_date;
    public String avatar_url;
    public String vote;
    public String name_family;
}
```

Now, I want to create an ArrayList consisting of those objects:

```
ArrayList<SubjectListStructure> nSubjects = = new ArrayList<SubjectListStructure>();
```

But now I can't check if `nSubjects` is empty or have some data like with this code:

```
public static Boolean ContainsAllNulls(ArrayList<SubjectListStructure> arrList)
{
    if(arrList != null)
    {
        for(SubjectListStructure a : arrList)
            if(a != null) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Or `nSubjects.isEmpty()` this solution and `ContainsAllNulls(nSubjects)` could not check correctly and return wrong result

Comment: Why would your ArrayList contain nulls in the first place? Can't you avoid adding nulls to it?

Comment: @Eran i want to only check thats is empty or no

Comment: And what ius your question exactly? Please respect the Java naming conventions, don't use raw ArrayList type, and use boolean rather than Boolean.

Comment: you could simply use the size method and check if it´s greater then 0?

Comment: @Kevin Esche size? `n_subjects.size()` ? can you paste correct code?

Comment: @TuxWorld yes 'n_subjects.size' will give you the amount of entries in your ArrayList, if it´s empty it returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should not allow `null`s in the list. In this case simply [`List.isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty--) will tell you if the list is empty.

If you can't or don't want to disallow `null`s, your code works and properly tests if the list only contains `null`s.

You don't even have to combine it with the `isEmpty()` method because the enhanced `for` works for empty lists and arrays too (in which case the body of the `for` will not be executed).

You can *generalize* your code to something like this which works for not just `ArrayList`s but for all [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)s (lists, sets, etc.) and with any element type not just your custom `SubjectListStructure` type:

```
public static boolean emptyOrAllNulls(Collection<?> c) {
    if (c != null)
        for (Object o : c)
            if(o != null)
                return false;

    return true;
}
```

Note that the enhanced `for` uses the [`Collection.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#iterator--) to obtain an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) to walk over elements of the collection. In case of empty collections it is more efficient to first check if the collection contains any elements and not go through the iterator:

```
public static boolean emptyOrAllNulls(Collection<?> c) {
    if (c != null && !c.isEmpty())
        for (Object o : c)
            if(o != null)
                return false;

    return true;
}
```